# How to get path of file located in the root directory in react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, mobile, react-native

I want to display a chart in a react-native app, for this i need to render a html file that i have in a folder placed in the root directory, using a Webview component. I've done this before for IOS, i used [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) to get the path of the file, but i'm having trouble trying to do the same for Android.

This is how i'm trying to get the file's path:

```
this.chartSource = 'file://' + RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/web/chart.html';
```

then i try to render it:

```
     <WebView
      source={{uri: this.chartSource}}
      style={{marginTop: 20}}
     />
```

This is the error message:

```
Encountered an error loading page ...
"net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND","loading":false,
"title":"","url":"file://data/data/com.therapyhelper/files/chart.html","target":32}
```